# Merge changes from remote branch

Tags: git

I started to learn Git and I'm stuck with one problem.

Let's say that there is one master repository and two forks.

master

-> fork1 -> my local clone

-> fork2

I'm working on one fork and I can pull changes from master repository and merge them with my own.
Now, let's say that some changes are made in one branch in second fork. How can I pull them and merge into my repo?

fork2 -> merge with my local clone -> push to fork1

Also, can I merge particular commit (by commit hash) from remote branch in second fork and how?

Thanks for your answers.

Answer (score 8, accepted):

Define your fork2 as a remote repo in your fork1

```
git remote add fork2 /path/to/fork2/repo
```

then fetch the changes from fork2

```
git fetch fork2
```

pull the changes from the fork2.

```
git pull fork2 <branch name>
```

A word of caution is the above command will update your current branch. So you should better use a tracking remote repo and review the changes and merge it to your branch in fork1 if you are ok with it.

```
git checkout --track -b branch_fork2 fork2/branch2
```

Review the code in your local branch named branch_fork2.

Checkout the repo where you'd like to merge your fork2 changes.

```
git checkout feature_1
```

Then merge it

```
git merge branch_fork2
```

If it results in merge conflicts, solve the merge conflicts and commit it.